# how to show dropdown data when edit? I'm using laravel and ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, select, ajaxform

I don't know how to say it. but

I wanna to edit this data, but why does the select/dropdown form not show the data before?
[this is my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65omj.png)

by the way, my CRUD just in one page index

Please help me

this is my Controller
[this is my controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMiRp.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaIvy.png)

And this is my blade file
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icYRg.png)

this is my Ajax syntax to edit the data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJzEh.png)

I hope to find a way soon. Or at least someone provides a reference to overcome this problem

Comment: No post your code as images, or links to images. **Code is text**, and can be copied, pasted and otherwise manipulated. **Images are static and cannot.** Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75881682/edit) and remove all images, and post your code as properly formatted text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

in your blade file just in your select div write the code check if the $prove id is similar to the $tkpmst id like below:

@if($tkmst_kostas->id == $prov->id) selected @endif